# Navbar problem when scroll down when collapse is open

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navbar it works well on large screens but on a small screen but when open collapse and scroll down navbar be disappearing and when scrolling up navbar appears with the open collapse
now how can stop the navbar when collapsing open

you can check the code from here: https://codepen.io/El7raq/pen/abwZORa

***HTML***

```
<nav class="navbar smart-scroll navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Product</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="./business-unit.html">Business Unit</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="./business-partners.html">Business Partners</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Solutions
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="./zoom.html">Zoom</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="./jabra.html">Jabra</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">News & Events</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

***CSS***

```
body {
  height: 1000px;
}
.smart-scroll{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
}
.scrolled-down{
    transform:translateY(-100%); transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.scrolled-up{
    transform:translateY(0); transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

***JS***

```
$('body').css('padding-top', $('.navbar').outerHeight() + 'px')

// detect scroll top or down
if ($('.smart-scroll').length > 0) { // check if element exists
    var last_scroll_top = 0;
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(scroll_top < last_scroll_top) {
            $('.smart-scroll').removeClass('scrolled-down').addClass('scrolled-up');
        }
        else {
            $('.smart-scroll').removeClass('scrolled-up').addClass('scrolled-down');
        }
        last_scroll_top = scroll_top;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `.scrolled-down` class, the `transform` CSS property has an attribute of `translateY(-100%)`. This implies scrolling up by 100% of the rendered height of nav bar `.smart-scroll`. Thus, the implementation would work as expected when the nav-bar is horizontal but fail when the nav-bar is vertical (on smaller screen widths) as the rendered height is much larger than the line height.

**Solution:**

JS

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
        scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(scroll_top < last_scroll_top) {
            $('.smart-scroll').removeClass('scrolled-down').addClass('scrolled-up');
        }
        else {
            var upOffset = $('.navbar-brand').height; //Added code
            $('.scrolled-down').css('transform', 'upOffset'); //Added code
            $('.smart-scroll').removeClass('scrolled-up').addClass('scrolled-down');
        }
        last_scroll_top = scroll_top;
});
```

CSS

```css
.scrolled-down{
    /*transform:translateY(-100%); Remove this property*/ 
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

The `.navbar-brand` class references to the navbar icon and is the closest to the line height of nav bar. Thus, the above implementation works well in a responsive environment.

Comment: Thank you, bro, for this solution helps but the navbar was stopping animate on all screens, I meant is that Navbar only stops moving when opened collapse on small or medium screens

Comment: On larger screens, the Navbar menu disappears, leaving behind the toggled drop-down. You would need the NavBar menu to remain visible at all times for ease of navigation. If not, then fixing the position of NavBar would be counter-productive.

Comment: You are welcome. You may mark the question as answered and upvote it. Thanks.